# Kubernetes CronJob - Do ConcurrencyPolicy and manual job execution/creation communicate with one another?

Tags: kubernetes-cronjob

I have a Kube cronjob that has a `concurrencyPolicy` of `Replace`. As I'd have expected, documentation suggests this means if there is a job running when the next cycle in the schedule is met while the previous job is running that the previous job would be killed off / cancelled.

What I want to know is, if I manually kick off a job with `kubectl create job --from`, does the concurrencyPolicy still play a part? It seems as though the answer is no from the testing I've been doing (and then I'll have multiple concurrent jobs), but would like to confirm.

If I'm correct and they don't work together, is there a way to have this functionality? Basically wanting to be able to deploy a job and then test it without having to wait around for it to kick off, but also don't want to have two jobs running at the same time.

Thanks!